# How to create content scroll like in https://xapo.com/wallet/

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to create content scroll like in https://xapo.com/wallet/?
Here is screenshot. Thx.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhlT2.png

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not have any code associated

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few really good javascript libraries that are often used to do stuff like this.  The site [ihatetomatoes.net](https://ihatetomatoes.net/) has a few good tutorials on two of the most popular ones (Skrollr and ScrollMagic).  Here's an [article](https://ihatetomatoes.net/skrollr-vs-scrollmagic/) (from ihatetomatoes.net) comparing the two.